# jquery datepicker validation not working properly

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I have the following code for a jquery date picker and I also have code to validate it. However, if you click in the box, the calendar comes up which is fine, but if you click away and don't choose a date, it is still marked as green (validated).

```
<script>
  // Validate Week Ending Date
  function validateSelect(element_94_datepick){
    if(document.getElementById('element_94_datepick').selectedIndex !== 0){
      document.getElementById('element_94_datepick').style.background ='#ccffcc';
      document.getElementById('datepickError').style.display = "none";
      return true;
    }else{
      document.getElementById('element_94_datepick').style.background ='#e35152';
      document.getElementById('datepickError').style.display = "block";
      return false;
    }
  }

</script>

<script>
  function validateForm(){
    // Set error catcher
    var error = 0;

    if(!validateSelect('element_94_datepick')){
      document.getElementById('datepickError').style.display = "block";
      document.getElementById('element_94_datepick').focus();
      error++;
    }

    // Don't submit form if there are errors
    if(error > 0){
      return false;
    }
  }

    </script>

  <script>
    $(function() {
      $( "#element_94_datepick" ).datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
        beforeShowDay: function(date) {
          var day = date.getDay();
          return [(day != 1 && day != 2 && day != 3 && day != 4 && day != 5 && day != 6)];
        }
      });
    });
  </script>
```

My input looks like below:

```
<td>
  <input type="text" class="formfield" id="element_94_datepick" name="element_94_datepick" value="" onblur="validateSelect(element_94_datepick)"/>
  <span id="datepickError" style="display: none;">You must select a Week Ending Date</span>
</td>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you just looking to see if there's a value entered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have jquery so I removed some of the getElementById calls and used jquery, but here's a start.

```
<td>
    <input type="text" class="formfield" id="element_94_datepick" name="element_94_datepick" value="" onblur="validateSelect('element_94_datepick')" /> <span id="datepickError" style="display: none;">You must select a Week Ending Date</span>

</td>
```

javascript

```
 // Validate Week Ending Date
  function validateSelect(element_94_datepick) {
      var field = $("#" + element_94_datepick)
      if (field.val() !== "") {
          field.css('background-color', '#ccffcc');
          document.getElementById('datepickError').style.display = "none";
          return true;
      } else {
          field.css('background-color', '#e35152');
          document.getElementById('datepickError').style.display = "block";
          return false;
      }
  }

  function validateForm() {
      // Set error catcher
      var error = 0;

      if (!validateSelect('element_94_datepick')) {
          document.getElementById('datepickError').style.display = "block";
          document.getElementById('element_94_datepick').focus();
          error++;
      }

      // Don't submit form if there are errors
      if (error > 0) {
          return false;
      }
  }

  $(function () {
      $("#element_94_datepick").datepicker({
          dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
          beforeShowDay: function (date) {
              var day = date.getDay();
              return [(day != 1 && day != 2 && day != 3 && day != 4 && day != 5 && day != 6)];
          },
          onSelect: function() { validateSelect('element_94_datepick'); }
      });
  });
```

working example: http://jsfiddle.net/cJy9z/1/